# Get a pixel from a relative x,y position on a scaled down UI Image in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find a pixel on an image object at the relative position Vector2(50,60). But, although the object is only 100x100, my image is 1200x1200 (for resolution scaling purposes). When I try to do:

```
Color color = mask.sprite.texture.GetPixel(x, y);
```

It returns the pixel from (50,60) on the image, and not on the gameobject (50,60 on the image is always a blank pixel)

My question: how to find out the pixel color on a downscaled gameobject UI image at the desired gameobject position.

Comment: `x / currentSizeX * originalSizeX `?

Comment: U have many options, your main problem is basically mapping your 50, 60 coordinates to your 1200x1200 range. U could as well look up the texture coordinates of the selected object (`RaycastHit.textureCoord`). and then do a texture Lookup. Your current post has to less information to give you the right answer as code.

Comment: I thought unity would have some out-of-the-box function for that, but I'll go with @Draco18s 's answer. I'm not sure but it seems to me that raycasting would perform slower than calculating and scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the position with respect to the scaling.

```
Vector2 originalResolution = new Vector2(1200, 1200);
Vector2 scaledResolution = new Vector2(100, 100);
Vector2 colorPixelPos = new Vector2(50, 60);
Vector2 actualPixelPos = new Vector2(colorPixelPos.x * scaledResolution.x / originalResolution.x, colorPixelPos.y * scaledResolution.y / originalResolution.y);
Color color = mask.sprite.texture.GetPixel((int)actualPixelPos.x, (int)actualPixelPos.y);
```